# Glossaries/Polyglossia error that occurs when Farsi is the default language

Tags: glossaries, persian

In the MWE below, I get an error on `\glsaddall` when the default language of the document is Farsi, but not when it is English.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}

% the error goes away with this
%\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
%\setotherlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}

\setmainfont{Adobe Arabic}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\farsifont{Adobe Arabic}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{entry}{name={some entry},description={some description}}
\glsaddall % error occurs here
% \glsadd{entry} % this triggers the same error
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Here is the portion of the log.

```
! Extra \else.
<argument> \else 
l.20 \printglossary
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
```

Is there anything that can be done about this? I tried switching the order of the packages, but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ulrike's answer certainly addresses the problem, but adds the complication that `glossaries` prints a Farsi number in the `.glo` file (۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰ instead of 1234567890), which confuses `xindy`. (I searched but was unable to find a way to teach `xindy` about non-Western numbers.) If one instead uses `xepersian`, this problem goes away.

(For other languages, of course, Ulrike's solution may be better. We happen to have very good packages available for typesetting Persian text.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Script=arab,Scale=1.4,Ligatures={NoCommon}]{Adobe Arabic}
\setlatintextfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU,ItalicFont=Charis SIL Italic,BoldFont=Charis SIL Bold]{Charis SIL}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{entry}{name={some entry},description={some description}}
\glsaddall
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, xindy can learn new "numbering schemes" (but not sure if it will like unicode), will try to check later.

Comment: You can teach xindy new numbering schemes. See e.g. http://www.xindy.org/doc/tutorial-3.html#ss3.1

Answer (score 1):

glossaries redefines \number locally (probably not a really good idea) and this breaks the farsi numbers. You can get around it like this (but I don't know if this will give the correct output in the glossaries). But imho you should make a bug report for glossaries, quite a number of languages try to change the number format and rely on the \number primitive.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}

% the error goes away with this
%\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
%\setotherlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}

\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\farsifont{Arial Unicode MS}

\makeglossaries

\makeatletter
\let\farsiorgnumber\number %save number
\def\farsinumber#1{%
  \if@western@numerals
    \number#1%
  \else
    \ifnum\XeTeXcharglyph"06F0 > 0%
      \farsidigits{\farsiorgnumber#1}%changed
      %%{\protect\addfontfeature{Mapping=farsidigits}\number#1}%
    \else%
      \arabicdigits{\farsiorgnumber#1}%changed
      %%{\protect\addfontfeature{Mapping=arabicdigits}\number#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}


\newglossaryentry{entry}{name={some entry},description={some description}}

 \glsaddall % error occurs here
 \glsadd{entry} % this triggers the same error


\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that `\number\c@page` must be deferred until the next paragraph break, but any other counter shouldn't be deferred. There's a hook to allow for other formats so you could try `\renewcommand\@wrglossarynumberhook{\let\number\orgnumber}` to counteract the change but test to see what happens when an entry is indexed at the start of a page in a paragraph that spans the page break.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Why can't you use the same method as the \label command? It is quite able to output the current counter but wait for the page number for the next page break (I assume that you meant the next page break).

Comment: I did originally, but it's a lot more complicated than `\label`. Some elements need to be expanded immediately and some have to be deferred. That's why `\glsaddprotectedpagefmt` is provided for additional numbering systems.

Comment: I don't think that `\glsaddprotectedpagefmt` works here. After `\glsaddprotectedpagefmt{@farsi@digits}`  xelatex hangs.

Comment: `\glsaddprotectedpagefmt` expects a command name that can accept a count register as the argument so it won't work with `@farsi@digits`. It works fine for me if I just add `\glsaddprotectedpagefmt{@arabic}` to the OP's MWE. (That's one that ought to be automatically added, and will be in the next version.)

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Nicola, your fix also works. But both approaches create another problem (as I discuss in my alternate answer): printing a Farsi number to the `.glo` file. `xindy` only seems to be able to tolerate Western numbers in locations. Could `glossaries` always print Western numbers?

Comment: (I guess I shouldn't say that `xindy` can't tolerate Western numbers. That may be possible. But all the defaults, and the module `glossaries` generates, are geared toward Western numbers.)